# How can I speed up reading files?

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with several volumes (3D images) composed of series of tif images. As they are really heavy, I only read a 100th portion of the width of each image which is enough for my purposes, but as my volumes weight around 170 GB each, the process is really slow. I have developed the following function to do so but I do not know how I could speed the process up more.

```
def load_partial_volume(self, folder):
    files = sorted(
        [file for file in os.listdir(folder) if file.endswith(".tif") or file.endswith(".tiff")]
    )

    def load_file(file):
        with tifffile.TiffFile(os.path.join(folder, file)) as tif:
            array = tif.asarray(out="memmap")
            new_width = array.shape[1] // 100
            return array[:, array.shape[1] // 2 : array.shape[1] // 2 + new_width]

    # Pre-allocate the numpy array for the volume
    sample_image = tifffile.imread(os.path.join(folder, files[0]))
    volume_shape = (len(files), sample_image.shape[0], sample_image.shape[1] // 100)
    volume = np.empty(volume_shape, dtype=sample_image.dtype)

    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        # Submit all tasks and get future objects
        futures = [executor.submit(load_file, file) for file in files]

        # Wait for all futures to complete, preserving the order
        for idx, future in enumerate(futures):
            try:
                volume[idx] = future.result()  # This preserves the order
                if (idx + 1) % 100 == 0:
                    logging.info(f"Loading partial volume - processed {idx + 1} files")
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"File processing generated an exception: {e}")

    logging.info("Finished loading partial volume")
    return volume.transpose(2, 1, 0)
```

Comment: I don't think there can be any miracle here. Reading the file from disk is probably the slow part, and you can't really avoid it. Tiff file may be compressed, which means that reading everything is necessary to get only one part. Well, maybe not everything. But way more than the extract your are interested in. And even if it is not compressed, or if it is compressed by batches that allow partial read, in your case, since you are extracting in `W` dimension, your are pretty much doomed to read everything.

Comment: I mean, it is like reading `..........XX..........XX..........XX..........XX..........XX..........` from the disk. Even if you are interested in only `XX` you probably have to read the whole string.  It might be possible (don't know how. Maybe it would work by doing nothing specific, since you mmap the file) if you were trying to read `..............................XXXXXXXXXX..............................`. There, there might be a chance that it is able to `seek` directly to or near the area you are interested in, and skip some actual reading.

Comment: So, if that is an option for you, I would try getting only 1% of the height instead of 1% of the width. Or I would precompute once for all some extract of your files in smaller files.

Comment: maybe estimating the amount of data to be read? `tif.asarray(out="memmap", buffersize=XYZ)`, see [src](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/blob/master/tifffile/tifffile.py#L4204)

Comment: Are you sure `TiffFile` do not load the entire file already? Are tiff file compressed? What is their 2D size? If so, the GIL may be the bottleneck. What kind of storage device you have? If you have a HDD, then using multiple thread is certainly bad for performance. Besides, yes, as pointed out by chrslg, the OS reach chunks from the disk, not just the requested items. It needs at least to fill a 4KiB page (generally much more due to *prefetching*, like up to few MiB). Did you profile your code? What resource is the bottleneck and which part? Critical details are missing.

Comment: `tif.asarray` likely reads/decodes the whole image from file. It depends on the layout of the image data in the TIFF files what is the best strategy to read only parts of the image. Try the [zarr interface](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/blob/5ced58caa74936ecc53f58ade94938e251e83138/tifffile/tifffile.py#L705-L716).